# Bootstrap Tour - Force hover on element

Tags: javascript

```
{
element: ".tour-step.tour-step-2",
placement: "rig",
title: "Datamodel",
onShown: function (tour) {
let showmodell = document.getElementById('step1');
$(showmodell).trigger("mouseover");
},
content: 'Here you will find...'
},
```

---

```
<li class="tour-step tour-step-2" id="step1">
...
    </li>
```

---

Im trying to force a pseudo class on an element when step1 of the tour is triggered.

Thank you for any help

Comment: `document.getElementById('.step1');` you shouldn't have a dot before step1.  also I don't think  you can affect the pseudo element with js unless you do it with css and change the parent element class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pete's suggestion solved my question:

```
             {
                 element: ".tour-step.tour-step-2",
                 placement: "top",
                 title: "Datamodel",
                 onShown: function (tour) {
                    let showmodell = document.getElementById('step1');
                    $(showmodell).css("display", "block");
                 },
                 content: 'Here you will find...'
             },
```

Would like to know why triggering a "mouseover" doesn't work in this case, though.